# How to partition a collection based on summing of item properties, up to a given limit?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

How can I chunk a collection into N chunks, based on summing one of the fields of each item in the collection, up to a given max value?

E.g. given the following:

```
class FileObject { public long sizeInBytes; }
Collection<FileObject> files;
long MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100 MB
```

I'd like to transform items into a `Collection<Collection<FileObject>>`, with the smallest number of inner collections, and satisfying the predicate that for each collection, the sum of the `sizeInBytes` of each element is less than `MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD`.

Taking this further, in addition to the above requirement, if `FileObject` is extended to contain a timestamp, I'd also like to partition the result by year, month, and day.

E.g.

```
class FileObject { public long sizeInBytes; public long modifiedDate; }
```

I'd like the end result to look like:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Collection<FileObject>>>>
```

where the keys in the maps are: year, month, and day (corresponding to the `FileObject`'s `modifiedDate`), and the Collection contains all files within that year, month, day, and where the sum of the sizeInBytes of each file is less than `MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD`.

Can both operations be done while avoiding loops and using functional constructs available using the Stream API or other? Can both be done in a single statement?

Comment: single statement - no, custom collector - yes, but the it would much be like whatever you would write with a loop anyway; in parallel you would have to merge `Map`s it seems and this is expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `StreamEx.collapse(...)` in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex). Here are the sample codes:

```
final long MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 12; // only for test purpose.

// create the sample file objects with random size for test.
Collection<FileObject> files =
    new Random().longs(0, 1000).limit(50).mapToObj(n -> new FileObject(n % 15, n))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// here is the final solution you can try
final MutableLong remaining = MutableLong.of(MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD);

List<List<FileObject>> result = StreamEx.of(files).collapse((a, b) -> {
  if (b.sizeInBytes <= remaining.value() - a.sizeInBytes) {
    remaining.subtract(a.sizeInBytes);
    return true;
  } else {
    remaining.setValue(MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    return false;
  }
}, Collectors.toList()).toList();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

And here is the solution by nested `groupingBy` for part 2 of your question:

```
// import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<FileObject>>>> result2 = files.stream()
    .filter(f -> f.sizeInBytes < MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD)
    .collect(groupingBy(f -> f.getYear(), 
                        groupingBy(f -> f.getMonth(), 
                                        groupingBy(f -> f.getDay(), toList()))));

result2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Finally here is the `FileObject` I used for test:

```
static class FileObject {
  public long sizeInBytes;
  public long modifiedDate;

  public FileObject(long sizeInBytes, long modifiedDate) {
    this.sizeInBytes = sizeInBytes;
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
  }

  public int getYear() {
    return (int) modifiedDate / 100; // only for test purpose
  }

  public int getMonth() {
    return (int) (modifiedDate % 100) / 10; // only for test purpose
  }

  public int getDay() {
    return (int) modifiedDate % 10; // only for test purpose
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return sizeInBytes + "-" + modifiedDate;
  }
}
```

**Updated based on the comments:**

You will need `Collectors.collectAndThen`.

```
Function<List<FileObject>, List<List<FileObject>>> finisher = fileObjs -> {
  MutableLong remaining2 = MutableLong.of(MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
  return StreamEx.of(fileObjs).collapse((a, b) -> {
    if (b.sizeInBytes <= remaining2.value() - a.sizeInBytes) {
      remaining2.subtract(a.sizeInBytes);
      return true;
    } else {
      remaining2.setValue(MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
      return false;
    }
  }, toList()).toList();
};

Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<List<FileObject>>>>> result4 = files.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(f -> f.getYear(),
        groupingBy(f -> f.getMonth(), 
            groupingBy(f -> f.getDay(), collectingAndThen(toList(), finisher)))));
```

And the result type should be `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<List<FileObject>>>>>`, not `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<FileObject>>>>`.

By the way, if you don't want to write `finisher` Function(I don't :-)), try my library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
Function<List<FileObject>, List<List<FileObject>>> finisher2 = fileObjs -> Seq.of(fileObjs)
    .split(MutableLong.of(0), (f, sizeSum) -> sizeSum.addAndGet(f.sizeInBytes) <= MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD,
        sizeSum -> sizeSum.setValue(0));

// import static com.landawn.abacus.util.stream.Collectors.MoreCollectors.*;
StreamEx.of(files)
    .toMap(f -> f.getYear(),
        groupingBy(f -> f.getMonth(),
            groupingBy(f -> f.getDay(), collectingAndThen(toList(), finisher2))));
```

Comment: The StreamEx::collapse looks very interesting, thanks! For the second part of the question, what I was looking for is for the total size of List<FileObject> to be less than MAX_SIZE_THRESHOLD, not each individual FileObject. In other words, incorporating the first part of the question.